# Centos 5.5 - Installing Git circular dependencies

Tags: git, dependencies, circular-dependency, centos5

Okay...I'm really getting a bit frustrated with this. I know that this post will border on duplication of other posts, none of the others I've looked at seem to address this issue in particular. So, please don't be in a hurry to slate it as a duplicate before at least verifying everything I have here.

I am trying to install git on my Centos5.5 server. Performing a yum install git-all ends up throwing a bunch of missing dependency errors. So, then I went to find the individual rpms;

1) perl-Git-1.7.4.1-1.el5.x86_64.rpm

```
git = 1.7.4.1-1.el5 is needed by perl-Git-1.7.4.1-1.el5.x86_64
```

2) git-1.7.4.1-1.el5.x86_64.rpm

```
perl(Git) is needed by git-1.7.4.1-1.el5.x86_64
perl-Git = 1.7.4.1-1.el5 is needed by git-1.7.4.1-1.el5.x86_64
```

Does anyone else see that this is an impossible installation as this forms an insoluble circular dependency?

I need to have git on this box as it's critical to my developments. Has anyone else found a decent work around for this?

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using `rpm` directly, you can use `--nodeps` to install one of the packages without checking dependencies, then install the other.

Comment: Thanks, Amber. Won't that cause possible issues if the package depends on other stuff that may be getting missed also?

Comment: I got it to work. I think that my issue was that I was trying to install each rpm individually. When I performed an rpm -i with both perl-git and git, it took. Thanks, Amber!

Comment: Ah, yeah, I assumed that you were doing it as a single command with everything (in which case it realizes the dependencies will be satisfied).